# Sequelize - After findAll, delete with a single query

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a table with an associated table. I am using `beforeDestroy` to remove any associated records up deletion.

```
Model.beforeDestroy(async (category: any) => {
  const items = await Category.findAll({
    where: {
      category_id: category.id,
    },
    attributes: ['id'],
    raw: true,
  });

  console.log(items); // [ { id: 2 }, { id: 3364 }, { id: 3365 } ]

  items.map((item: any) => {
    Category.destroy({ where: { id: item.id } });
  });
});
}
```

I am trying to delete the matching items with a single `destroy` query rather than mapping through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Category.destroy({ where: { id:items.map(item=>item.id)} });
```